# Unhandled exception while assigning strings. C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and I write in c++.
I have a rather weird problem with my code.

```
void CMap::loadMap(const std::string &MapName)
{
    m_MapName   = MapName; // This line is causing an error
    loadMap();
}
```

While it compiles succesfully, it crashes on that line when I run it.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x003A10FC (msvcr110d.dll) in MyAdventure.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFEEEFEEE.
```

That's what it says. When i click Break, it directs me to that line in memcpy.asm

```
mov     [edi],al        ;U - write second byte to destination
```

CMap is a class which has

```
std::string m_MapName;
```

as it's member.
I've also tried to compile my code in Visual Studio 2010 Express and it works fine without any problems. I'd really want to use VS 2012 though, so I'd really like some help.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please make a complete, compileable example. I'm pretty sure `FEEEFEEE` is a "special poison value", that MS uses to fill memory that has either been deleted or not been initialized or some such, so your CMap object that you are using is probably "bad".

Comment: Second @MatsPetersson

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Well, when I commented out all the code except for this loadMap bit, it started to work again. I'm going to post some files here: http://pastebin.com/Gu3bNLGs
If you need more, please tell me.

Comment: May be the memory is getting corrupted because of over-write etc.